# XPath get name of node where attribute has a certain value

Tags: java, xpath

I have the following piece of the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xmi:XMI xmi:version="20131001" xmlns:xmi="http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:SecureUML="http://RootElement/schemas/SecureUML/_zVWe83m5Eeae1LmHHETvPg/99" xmlns:ecore="http://www.eclipse.org/emf/2002/Ecore" xmlns:uml="http://www.eclipse.org/uml2/5.0.0/UML" xsi:schemaLocation="http://RootElement/schemas/SecureUML/_zVWe83m5Eeae1LmHHETvPg/99 ../SecureUML/SecureUML.profile.uml#_zVWe9Hm5Eeae1LmHHETvPg">
...
<SecureUML:Role xmi:id="_6l9aEKgBEea49okOlb9Hog" base_Classifier="_0YCfQKgBEea49okOlb9Hog"/>
<SecureUML:Role xmi:id="_7aToIKgBEea49okOlb9Hog" base_Classifier="_3xegQKgBEea49okOlb9Hog"/>
```

How can I get the name of the node where the `base_Classifier` is for example `_0YCfQKgBEea49okOlb9Hog` or `_3xegQKgBEea49okOlb9Hog`? These 2 strings I have them in an `ArrayList` so I do smth like:

```
String tmp = items.get(j).getId();
String stereotypes = "//*[@base_Classifier="+tmp+"]";  
NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xpath.compile(stereotypes)
    .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

but the `nodeList1` is empty.

I mention that I want for both `_0YCfQKgBEea49okOlb9Hog` and `_3xegQKgBEea49okOlb9Hog` to obtain `SecureUML:Role`.

I also mention that I registered the namespace with smth like

```
HashMap<String, String> prefMap = new HashMap<String, String>() {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     {
         put("xmi", "http://www.omg.org/spec/XMI/20131001");
         put("SecureUML", "http://RootElement/schemas/SecureUML/_zVWe83m5Eeae1LmHHETvPg/99");
     }
};
```

Many thanks in advance!

Madalina

Answer (score 0):

Your `XPath` predicate is not correct as the type of your attribute is obviously a `String` not a `Number`, so you need to put your attribute's value **between double or single quotes**, then call `getNodeName()` to get the name of the node, as next:

```
String stereotypes = String.format("//*[@base_Classifier=\"%s\"]", tmp);
NodeList nodeList1 = (NodeList) xpath.compile(stereotypes)
   .evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
System.out.println(nodeList1.item(0).getNodeName());
```

**Output:**

```
SecureUML:Role
```